# Irrational sum to integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is it possible for $(a-b)k + bf$ to be an integer if $k,f$ are irrational numbers and $a,b$ are integers? What about  $(a-b)k - bf$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(0-1)\sqrt2+1\cdot\sqrt2=0$$

$$(2-1)\sqrt2-1\cdot\sqrt2=0$$

---

In general this is possible, if and only if the set $\{1,k,f\}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. This is close to being a tautology, as seen by the following argument.

Assume the set $\{1,k,f\}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then by clearing the denominators we get a linear dependency relation with integral coefficients $c_i,i=1,2,3$:
$$
c_1k+c_2f=c_3.
$$
Set $c_2=\pm b$ (the sign depending on the case you are interested in) and solve $a$ from the equation $a-b=c_1\implies a=b+c_1$.

On the other hand, if
$$
(a-b)k\pm bf=c
$$
with integers $a,b,c$, then clearly $\{1,k,h\}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence also over the rationals.

---

So for example you can do this with $k=1+\sqrt2$ and $f=\sqrt2$. Or $k=45+17\sqrt{17}$ and $f=-4+\sqrt{17}$. OTOH you cannot do it with $k=\sqrt2$ and $f=\sqrt3$.

Linear dependence over the rationals may not sound like a very useful tool here unless you are familiar with elementary theory of field extensions. That theory will give you useful criteria for deducing linear independence over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But if $k,f$ and $1$ are linearly independent over the rationals, then it is not possible.

Comment: Is that the only case where it is possible? (equaling 0)

Comment: Of course not. You want a general criterion?

Comment: Yes, please (10char)

Comment: In particular (just because I suspect the OP cares about this?), it is possible to have $c_3$ be any integer whatsoever: for any integer $c$, it is possible to find irrational numbers $k$ and $f$, and integers $a$ and $b$, such that $(a-b)k + bf = c$.

Comment: I think I need to look up what it means to be linearly dependent -- I don't fully understand the answer. One moment

Comment: Good luck! Once you absorb the definition of linear dependence over rationals, you will see that the answer is quite trivial. The useful things come from field theory, when you get tools for showing linear independence.

Comment: @user2367428: Very roughly, for the purposes here, it means that both $k$ and $f$ are irrational "for the same reason", or that their "irrational part" is the same. For example, they could be $2+7\sqrt{3}$ and $5-8\sqrt{3}$, or $5\pi-13$ and $6+3\pi$, or $1+2(e+\sqrt{7})$ and $9(e+\sqrt{7})$. But they cannot be $2+\pi$ and $3-e$ or $\sqrt{11}$ and $\sqrt{5}$. The actual definition is that you can can write $c_1k+c_2f=c_3$ for integers $c_1,c_2,c_3$, i.e. it is possible to get rid of the irrational part by some suitable combination, which is close to exactly what you want (as Jyrki says).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Say I can write an irrational number in the form $n + i$ for integer $n$ and irrational fraction portion $i$. Then you are saying that the $i$'s must equate?

Comment: No. There is no such a thing as an irrational part. Linear dependence (over Q) for a set of numbers $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ means just that there exist a non-trivial set of rational coefficients $q_i$ such that
$$q_1x_1+q_2x_2+\cdots+q_nx_n=0.$$ You can always clear the denominators to make all the $q_i$:s integers. So for example $x_1=\sqrt3/2$ and $x_2=3\sqrt3$ are dependent because
$$6x_1-x_2=0.$$ Just like linear dependence of vectors, but now we only allow rational coefficients. For another example $\sqrt2$ and $1+\sqrt2$ are independent, but the triplet $\{1,\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2\}$ is not.

Comment: @user2367428: No, it's not necessary that the fractional parts must be equal. Try it with the pairs of examples I gave in my previous comment. For example $2 + 7\sqrt{3} \approx 14.124$ has fractional part $7\sqrt{3} - 12 \approx 0.124$, and $5 - 8\sqrt{3} \approx -9 + 0.14359$ has fractional part $14 - 8\sqrt{3} \approx 0.14359$. But even though their fractional parts are not equal, we have facts like $8(2+7\sqrt{3}) + 7(5-8\sqrt{3}) = 51$. Just carefully read what Jyrki suggests.